# Knockout Dropdown Replace on item

Tags: knockout.js, drop-down-menu, null

The data I’m receiving back has a null element in some cases.

The issue is with the binding, I was wondering if I could do a replace however I get an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: item.FullAddress(...).
>
> Replace is not a function

Is there another way to do this?

```
optionsText: function(item) { return item.FullAddress().Replace(', , ', ', ') }
```

Thanks in advance

Clare

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript is case-sensitive language, the `String` object has method called [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and not `Replace`.

Try to use this instead:

```
return item.FullAddress().replace(', , ', ', ')
```

Also it's a good practice to separate your logic from presentation. So add new `computed` property

```
this.fullAddressFormatted = ko.computed(function () {
   return item.FullAddress().replace(', , ', ', ')
}, this);
```

and use `optionsText: fullAddressFormatted` binding.